# Handlebar variable inside {{}}?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, metalsmith

How can I use a variable containing string 'nav' (from a markdown file) instead of nav (a json file) in:
`{{#each nav}}
{{this}}
{{/each}}`

  As I have more than one nav.json file, if I use a variable from the respective markdown file, I want it to loop through the respective json file with the same filename as the variable from markdown.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your Question is not clear that what condition you want to achieve.

so i guess an one attempt that, Use JavaScript Array Variable like the object of  language Array you mentioned

```
var language = ['english','marathi','hindhi','telugu'];
var result = [];

 language.forEach(function(eachElement) {
      // roam here if you want to do more .....
     result.push('nav'+eachElement.charAt(0));
  });
```

so the result would be 
 `['nave','navm', 'navh', 'navt']`

After that use this `result Array` in Handlerbar #each loop as your condition